# ResultSet Jasper Exception

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to get the top products voted with the method below.

You can see that I am first getting the list of all products and store result in results and for each product I am getting the votes and storing it in results2. For some reason an error is popping up when trying to `results2.getInt("Id")`. Thanks

```
public ArrayList<Product> getPollResults() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    ArrayList<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM products";
    connect();        
    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet results = (ResultSet)ps.executeQuery();        
    while(results.next()){
        query= "SELECT COUNT('Votes') AS Votes, pro.Id, pro.ProductDescription, pro.productFileName FROM products pro"
                 +   " JOIN polls poll ON pro.Id = poll.ProductNumber"
                   + " WHERE pro.Id = '"+ results.getInt("Id") +"'";
        ps = (PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet results2 = (ResultSet)ps.executeQuery();   

        myProducts.add(new Product(results2.getInt("Id"), results2.getString("pro.ProductDescription"), results2.getString("pro.productFileName"), results2.getInt("Votes")));
    }        
    disconnect();   
    return myProducts;
}
```

Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /polls.jsp at line 24

21:             </div>
22:             <div id="main-container">
23:                 <%db.DBConnection db = new  db.DBConnection(); 
24:                 ArrayList<Product> myProducts =db.getPollResults();
25:                 %>  
26:                 <h1>Polls</h1>
27:                   <form id="Gadgets" action="Gadgets.jsp" method="post">
```

Comment: can you post whole stack trace? The error does not say anything

Comment: Please give exceptions a bit more love and attention. Your exception says that "an exception occurred". It would make sense to take a look further above or down in the stack trace to find exactly that exception. Further, this problem has nothing to do with JSP. You'd have exactly the same problem when executing this code in a plain vanilla Java class with a `main()` method. Even then, writing Java code in JSP files is a bad practice.